# Getting GPS data in the background on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, background, gps

I know others have asked this question, and I have read all the replies, but my code still isn't working and I'm at a loss.

All I'm trying to do is get notified of significant location changes while the app is running in the background.

Here's what I have so far:

In my AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"Background");

    [self.viewController.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

In my ViewController.m:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation");
    NSLog(@"newLocation: %@", newLocation);

}
```

This works fine when the app is in the foreground, but not in the background.

I trigger the GPS change, I am switching the location using the iPhone simulator.  Does this possibly not fire background events?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Bryan